# MySQL Read vs Write Lock

Tags: mysql, locking

I'd like for a client session to lock a table, so that it can continue to read from and write to that table. At the same time other client sessions should only be able to read from the table. Once the lock is removed, then all client sessions should be allowed to read from and write to the table. Also once the lock is removed, all client sessions that tried to write to the table while it was locked should execute. I don't want any errors thrown on attempted inserts during the lock.

I know that a read lock wouldn't work because the client session that creates the lock can't write to the table while the lock exists. Also a write lock wouldn't work because other client sessions can't read from the table. Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: Locking tables is rarely the way to go. Write locks typically mean exclusive locks, meaning only the given connection can access the table. You may have to implement application level locking in this case.

Comment: You have not adequately explained why the standard `BEGIN; ((do read FOR UPDATE ... writes)) COMMIT;` is not sufficient.  Note the `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @RickJames `BEGIN; ((do read FOR UPDATE ... writes)) COMMIT;` seems like a good solution as long as other clients can continue to read from the table. It sounds like they can according to Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with table locks using the `LOCK TABLES` statement, for the reasons you stated in your question.

You could do it by creating row locks on all the rows of the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable FOR UPDATE;
```

The row locks would block any other sessions from writing until you commit your transaction, but they could read as long as they don't try to use locking read queries. Meanwhile, you could read or write the table since you already have locks on all the rows.

Another solution is to get a global lock, but don't use `LOCK TABLES`. I've coded systems where all participating clients need to acquire a lock with the [GET_LOCK() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html#function_get-lock) before writing to a table. But if they only need to read, they just skip the request for that lock. This would work, but it would require all clients to include code to support the same access policy.

Comment: `BEGIN; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable FOR UPDATE; COMMIT;` sounds like it might be what I'm looking for since other clients can still read from the table.